# php mysqli returning null rows after query

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.4

I've used this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sillaru_users AS users 
JOIN sillaru_users_data AS users_data 
ON users.id = users_data.user_id 
WHERE name = 'user_package_id' AND users.id = 2
```

in phpadmin its ok, but in the code it returns false, what can be the reason?

**UPDATE**

```
public function __construct($data)
{
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $this->$key = $value;
    }

    $this->conn = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    $this->conn->set_charset("utf8");
}

public function query($query)
{

    $this->result = $this->conn->query($query);
    return $this;
}


public function row()
{
    if($this->result)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->result);
        mysqli_free_result($this->result);
    }
    else
    {
        $row = false;
    }
    return $row;
}
```

HERE is the source of the db class, I call it like this:

```
    $node = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ".Config::$prefix."users AS users JOIN ".Config::$prefix,"users_data AS users_data ON users.id = users_data.user_id WHERE name = 'user_package_id' AND users.id = {$id}")->row();

var_dump($node); //boolean false
```

here it is any ideas?

**My Config:**

```
<?php

class Config
{

    public static $charset = 'UTF-8';
    public static $prefix = 'sillaru_';
    public static $maxUsersPerLevel = 3;

    public static $db = array(

        'localhost' => 'localhost',
        'prefix' => 'sillaru_',
        'db' => 'sillaru',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => ''
    );

    public static $currentApplication = 'sillaru';



}
```

my config file

Comment: Do you ever check for an error result from the query?  If so, where and what does it say?  If not, I'd try that (and make sure that `name` is not a column name in both tables.

Comment: @JeremyMiller I've tried var dump, and there are null values of all the properties, can't figure out whats going on because the query is valid(checked in the phpmyadmin sql prompt) the connection is stable

Comment: Could you show us the tables structures?

Comment: I think that during editing of this question, the PHP part was removed by accident.

Comment: @er_Rajendraa Why did you delete all the code form his question?

Comment: someone has edited it...

Comment: @Barmar I think that was a conflict of editing b/c the PHP was added after the post and Rajendraa's edit took time to get approved.

Comment: @Barmar i just edited it. i m not deleted any code.

Comment: What I meant, was not `var_dump`, but `echo $this->conn->error` per the mysqli error documentation ( http://php.net/mysqli_error )

Comment: You should use `users.name = 'user_package_id'`
use `die(mysqli_error());` to get the error message

Comment: Um, what is that hidden bit at the end of the query? `->row();` ?

Comment: I repeat the above sql works in phpmyadmin and its valid, but in the code it returns false

Comment: Repeating yourself is not necessary. Did you look at my question?  Far right of the query at the bottom of your post... there's extra code there.

Comment: @JeremyMiller That's not extra. `query` returns the class object, the `row` method returns a row of results.

Comment: that is the row of the above class, just checking if it returns false or a row depending on the $this->result

Comment: @Barmar Thanks.  That's new to me ( http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php ) does not document such a method.  Learn something new every day. :)

Comment: string 'La table 'sillaru.sillaru_' n'existe pas' (length=40) - this is what I've get by echo $this->db->conn->error, but the table exists and its specified, what is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `$Config::$prefix` is correct? Try echoing `$query` to make sure.

Comment: @JeremyMiller He's implemented his own DB class, the code is all in the question.

Comment: I repeat I've tried that query in phpmyadmin by echoing the whole query as a string it works and it is valid, but in the execution itself it returns false, thus in the class $this->result is null

Comment: It sounds like there's a space at the end of `$Config::$prefix`. Echo the whole `$query` and you'll probably see `sillaru.sillaru_ users`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks.  FFS it is hard to help people when they change things as it goes along.  Since the OP seems to like repeating over and over and over... I'm going to suggest that the OP look for a comma out of place and then stop listening to repeats.

Comment: @Barmar no there are no spaces, no commas out of space, I repeat I've echoed the whole query string and its valid and correct, the connection has no errors, but I can't understand why it returns false instead of a row, because in the pure sql command line it returns a row, what is wrong???

Comment: @JeremyMiller added my Config class

Comment: The error message says that the table name in the query is `sillaru.sillaru_`, so there must be a space after the prefix. If it's not in the `$prefix` variable, then it must be before `users` in the string you concatenate. Spaces don't just appear by themselves, they have to be in the code somewhere.

Comment: @Barmar Abhishek found the comma that was breaking the query.

Comment: I've checked the query string before it goes to the execution and is perfect, I'am stuck, I can't explain what exactly happens, because I can't understand whats going on

Comment: If you had done what I said and added `echo $query` you would have seen the problem that Abhishek found. Why can't you do simple, obvious debugging steps?

Comment: I think there are no deeper step than before the execution native function, is there anything more that I can provide to help you understand whats going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

error seems to be here on the line below near .Config::$prefix , -- where comma have to separated with dot.

```
$node = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ".Config::$prefix."users AS users JOIN ".Config::$prefix,"users_data AS users_data ON users.id = users_data.user_id WHERE name = 'user_package_id' AND users.id = {$id}")->row();

var_dump($node);
```

replace by below line

```
 $node = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ".Config::$prefix."users AS users JOIN ".Config::$prefix."users_data AS users_data ON users.id = users_data.user_id WHERE name = 'user_package_id' AND users.id = {$id}")->row();
```

Comment: the users table doesn't have a `name` field, it has `login` field, the `name` field belongs to users_data there no confusion

Comment: Ah, you found the line with the comma incorrect and just after the OP who edits their post changing things so that they can then just say, "I repeat" comments on your post, you edit it to replace the missing comma.  Well done.

Comment: @Abhishek Don't just show the code, explain what you changed and why.

Answer (score 0):

Use alias.* in place of *

```
 SELECT users.* FROM sillaru_users AS users 
 JOIN sillaru_users_data AS users_data 
 ON users.id = users_data.user_id 
 WHERE name = 'user_package_id' AND users.id = 2
```

Comment: That will reduce the number of columns shown, but won't change the number of rows.